# How do I lock a servo motor?

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, servo

I am working on a robot which uses Ackermann's steering principle. Now the steering principal itself is in the development stage and the first prototype is pretty much good except for the fact that it can get turned very easily.

So I was hoping to find a way to lock the servo operating the steering mechanism so that it only rotates when the servo does. Any way to do that??

I'm using a UNO.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you call `servo.detach()`? Servo's should usually hold their position when attached. This is because of the way how servo's work. They've got an internal feedback loop, which constantly adjusts the servo towards it's setpoint (if it's a bit off).

Comment: @Paul no I didn't

Comment: What type of servo do you have?

Comment: @Paul simple rc servo, Turnigy MX - 3505

Comment: It might not get enough current to hold it into position? If you touch it, would it jump back to it's position when you release it?

Comment: No it just moves with my steering mechanism as if moved by external force. I am giving it 5V 3 Amps through a UBEC and raw power from 2 ICR 16850 batteries, totalling somewhere near 8.5 V

Comment: Hobby servos are typically susceptible to backdriving when unpowered, and possibly also if they are powered but have no signal.  Counteracting backdriving would require that the internal control loop function, but a traditional analog implementation would have no memory of what the last commanded position was.  An MCU based servo could have such a memory, but its not clear it would be programmed to.  **Make sure you are continuing to send pulses to the servo and do not subject it to torque above its rating**.  This may turn out to be a mechanical design problem not an Arduino one.

Comment: It's *Ackermann* and *principle*.

What do you mean by "find a way to lock the servo operating the steering mechanism so that it only rotates when the servo does"? When *what* rotates?

Comment: @JayEye thanks for pointing that out. My design is just of wood and rotate s easily with any external force. I will control the rotation from my servo. So I want that my servo only moves when the Arduino tells it do so, otherwise stay "locked" in the centre position,

Comment: @ChrisStratton well that's most probably a mechanical problem, I can just counteract it by locking my servo.

Comment: Hobby servos do not offer "locking" as a feature.

Comment: This seems to be a question about servos rather than Arduinos, so I'm going to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normale servo will stay in position when:

1. It's powered up (with enough current)
2. You are feeding the control signal into it.

And

3. It's rated for the amount of force applied.

Based on your comments, it seems that it's not a regular servo or could be faulty.
I couldn't find the datasheet for your servo, so I can't tell if it's normal behavior, though it seems unlikely. (Servo's aren't made to bounce around)

Edit:
It doesn't really make sense that it could be easily rotated by touching it, that would also mean that it can't lift anything? I would suggest trying another servo.